# https to http redirect for a sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess file which redirects all pages to https

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?confetticostume\.ch 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'm trying to set up a dev area for testing a new multisite build but when i got to confefttibox.ch/0-NEWSTORE it is changing the url to https and then gives me a 404 error.

How can I change the htaccess rule to allow ALL pages within /0-NEWSTORE to be http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow all pages within /0-NEWSTORE to be https, you need to exclude them from the rule, To exclude pages, put the following condition above your rewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/0-NEWSTORE/.+$ [NC]
```